# Задать размер PDF

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать размер (А4, с отступами 0, 1.5, 2, 0 (см) от границы) pdf в DOMPDF, используя set_Paper?

Comment: $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');  string $orientation: 'portrait' or 'landscape'

Comment: @Даниил, а отступы как задать?

Comment: Укажите отступы в html и выведите его в pdf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779285/dompdf-html-to-pdf-cant-set-margin-of-page

Comment: @Даниил, спасибо